# 'Random_Number_File_Writer.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'saveFileDialog1_FileOk'

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch, savefiledialog

**'Random_Number_File_Writer.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'saveFileDialog1_FileOk' and no extension method 'saveFileDialog1)_FileOk' accepting a first argument of type 'Random_Number_File_Writer.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

That, is the error message that I am getting. I tried going to my college's lab for assistance, but the person is not familiar with C# and it took us around an hour just to get my line numbers showing (just for reference...) And then I went to my professor and he said he was going to be busy for a while.. So I thought I'd try here as an alternate source of help.

I looked at the questions already on here regarding similar errors, but it still leaves me puzzled as how to correct this one in particular, and as I referenced the code in my textbook as closely as possible, I'm not sure I understand why I'm even getting this error.

Here's the code, and I'm sorry if it's difficult to read. Oh, and I know that this is the part generating the error, because I had it running  yesterday, WITHOUT this part. But part of the assignment is having the save as dialog.

```
try
        {
            //Initial opening point for save file dialogue
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Heather\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Random Number File Writer";
            //Save As popup - Opening the file for writing usage once it's created.
            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                randomNumberFile = File.CreateText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
            else // Popup informing user that the data will not save to a file because they didn't save.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You elected not to save your data.");
            }
```

here's the using stuff that didn't format:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO; // Added to be able to use StreamWriter variable type
```

And here is the code snippet it gives when I double click and it takes me to the Form1.Designer.CS window.

```
            this.saveFileDialog1.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.saveFileDialog1_FileOk);
```

Comment: You've shown the *body* of the method, but not the method declaration. Presumably it *should* be called `saveFileDialog1_FileOk`...

Comment: Is this entirely winforms, or do you have WPF forms? if so, be sure to implement DialogResult.OK from windows.forms because WPF uses an incompatible definition for DialogResult.

Comment: I'm sorry Jon I'm not sure what that would do/where it would go. Is that like a variable declaration?

Comment: can you post the stacktrace, and the block of code that contains the lines indicated in it?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO; // Added to be able to use StreamWriter variable type @Frank

Comment: Well that didn't format properly. And it won't even compile

Comment: When I double click on the error in the error list, this is what it gives me **            this.saveFileDialog1.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.saveFileDialog1_FileOk);**

Comment: @user1839549 you can and should edit your question to include that kind of stuff

Comment: Ah. Thank you Sam. I'll do that now so it displays appropriately. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saveFileDialog1_FileOk`  Looks like it's supposed to be an event handler( a method) so make sure that you have a method like

```
public void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
}
```

in your `Form1` class

Comment: Allright. I'm apparently not the brightest crayon in the box today, but shouldn't (if someone were to hit cancel or click out with the x) the else statement take care of cancellation?

Comment: Stupid double click. Putting that (specifically, since I'm not sure how to edit it) gives more errors than the one I already had.  :D Hmm. Unless I put it in the wrong place. Let me shift that.

Comment: Aha. Had to lose the comma and the a. Now everything jives I think. It at least compiles. Thanks Sam!